# Power Query; Calculating when a certain value in numerical order is missing and creating an additional row

Tags: excel, transform, powerquery, excel-2016

I generate a report every week that identifies demands for parts that my company makes for the current week and future weeks. The report I generate loads data from a customer file which I download, transform and load into my report using Power Query. The report shows the week number for the year and the demand for that week. The problem I am facing is the customer report skips a week (week 26) and goes straight to 27 (View attached images).

What steps can I take in Power Query to calculate when a week number is missing and create an additional row for that week number and fill the Qty Required field with "0" while keeping the Current Balanced on Hand field the same as the previous week.

I have attached images of my table generated from PQ and of the PQ table in editor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* help. I started with a table similar to your screenshot:
[image]

Then I brought it into Power Query as Table1:
[image]

Then I added an Index column, starting with 1:
[image]
[image]

Then I added a Custom column to determine whether a week has been skipped. It uses the Index column and WeekNumber column for that. (The try otherwise handles an error that occurs when it gets to the last record.):
[image]
[image]

Then I filtered the Custom column to only show rows with "No":
[image]

Then, to add the missing weeks' records, I clicked the function button...[image]...and typed `= Table.TransformColumns(Custom1, {{"Qty Required", each 0},{"Requirement Date", each 0}, {"WeekNumber", each _ + 1}})` and pressed enter in the function bar area. I also changed the name of the Applied Step from Custom1 to Transform Table (at the right of the Power Query window):
[image]

Then I clicked Home > Append Queries and I picked Table1 in the dropdown, and I clicked OK. 
[image]

Then I changed the second instance of #"Transform Table" to #"Added Custom" in the function bar area and pressed enter. This appends the new records for the previously missing weeks with the ones that already existed previously, which existed in the #"Added Custom" Applied Step (which is also basically a previous table state) to make the complete set:
[image]

Then I sorted by the WeekNumber:
[image]

Then I removed the Index and Custom Columns:
[image]

Here's my M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Part Number", Int64.Type}, {"Part Description", type text}, {"Current Balance On Hand", Int64.Type}, {"Qty Required", Int64.Type}, {"Requirement Date", type datetime}, {"WeekNumber", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if  #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[WeekNumber]+1 = #"Added Index"{[Index]}[WeekNumber] then "Yes" else "No" otherwise "Yes"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = "No")),
#"Transform Table" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Qty Required", each 0},{"Requirement Date", each 0}, {"WeekNumber", each _ + 1}}),
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Transform Table", #"Added Custom"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Appended Query",{{"WeekNumber", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index", "Custom"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your effort and time spent helping me with this.